# Breast stroke kick with my face facing the sky! Am i back stroking in swimming?

Tags: swimming

today my coach (in swimming) taught me (after breast stroke) to kick backwards (as we do in breast stroke) with my head upside facing the air.

So what am i doing is like : having my face towards the sky and kicking in the water as we do in breast stroke.

But when I searched in internet i find that backstroke is something like having your hands move like freestyle.

So what movement am i doing now ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds a lot like the elementary backstroke. It uses the same kick as the breast stroke. To me, the arm motions also feel similar to the breast stroke, but it's as if you're doing them below your shoulders instead of above.

[Video example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uvn9QinYMQc)